# Dagger field injection not working with simple java classes

Tags: java, dagger-2, dagger

I am trying field injection with dagger although constructor injection is working absolutely fine but i don't know what is wrong with field injection. May be I am doing wrong. I am adding the code snippets. I am getting null pointer exception on engine.start() because the engine dependency is not fed. It is similar to A->B->C dependencies where A->B is fed but B->C is not. Its been long I am unable to resolve.

```
package com.raghav.java.car;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class App 
{
    @Inject 
    Car car;

    App() {
        DaggerCarComponent.create().inject(this);
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.perform();
    }

    private void perform() {
        car.run();

    }
}

public interface Engine {
    void start();
}

class FordEngine implements Engine {

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Engine started -- Vroom Vroom");
    }
}

public interface Car {
        void run();
}

class MarutiCar implements Car {

    @Inject
    Engine engine;

    public void run() {
        engine.start();
        System.out.println("WOW!! Maruti Running ");        
    }

}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = {CarModule.class})
public interface CarComponent {

    void inject(App app);

}

@Module
class CarModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public Car provideCar() {
        return new MarutiCar();
    }


    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public Engine provideEngine() {
        return new FordEngine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to do nested injection you need to use constructor injection otherwise that wont happen automatically because when you provide a dependency out of Dagger style (through constructor injection or argument injection in module) dagger has no idea about that. change your classes like below:

change your `MarutiCar` like this:

```
class MarutiCar implements Car {

Engine engine;

@Inject
public MarutiCar(Engine engine)
{
    this.engine = engine;
}

public void run() {
    engine.start();
    System.out.println("WOW!! Maruti Running ");        
    }

}
```

and your `FordEngine` class like this:

```
class FordEngine implements Engine {

@inject
public FordEngine()
{
}

public void start() {
    System.out.println("Engine started -- Vroom Vroom");
    }
}
```

then change your `CarModule` like below:

```
@Module
class CarModule {

@Singleton
@Provides
public Car provideCar(MarutiCar marutiCar) {
    return marutiCar;
    }

@Singleton
@Provides
public Engine provideEngine(FordEngine fordEngine) {
    return fordEngine;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: DAGGER WONT INJECT FIELDS OF A CLASS THAT IS NOT CREATED BY ITSELF.

you are creating the MarutiCar instance by your self how you expect dagger to know what it needs ? you can start a new chain of dagger creation in that class to achieve this which is a weird thing to do.
you need to tell dagger what you need by showing dependencies through constructor or module method argument so that dagger instantiate them for you to know what they need. dagger doesnt provide your nested dependencies injected fields because it hasnt created them so it has no idea about their dependencies, unless you start another chain of dagger creation like what you did in your `App` class.
there is another way if you dont want to use constructor injection which i only show this for you Car and `MarutiCar` class:

```
@Module
class CarModule {

@Singleton
@Provides
public Car provideCar(Engine engine) {
    MarutiCar marutiCar = new MarutiCar(engine);
    }

@Singleton
@Provides
public Engine provideEngine(FordEngine fordEngine) {
    return fordEngine;
    }
}
```

and the MarutiCar class would be like this (no need for @inject)

```
class MarutiCar implements Car {

Engine engine;

public MarutiCar(Engine engine)
{
    this.engine = engine;
}

public void run() {
    engine.start();
    System.out.println("WOW!! Maruti Running ");        
    }

}
```

Comment: Ya constructor injection is working absolutely fine as written above but why field injection is not working? and can you show the instance where it is written "to do nested injection you need to use constructor injection otherwise that wont happen automatically". Why it is not possible to have field injection in nested dependencies. And there is one question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28330117/dagger-nested-injections-is-it-necessary-to-call-inject which shows field injection is possible in dagger1 then why cant this be possible in dagger2. And thanks for replying!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694326/nested-recursive-injections-with-dagger   look at this link. it explains why this happens.

Comment: Dagger is responsible to create your dependencies not to inject their injected fields unless you create the component in them too. dagger only provides the dependencies which is obligatory to create a instance (adding a @inject to construction). it does not search and inject for every field in that dependency.

Comment: if you dont want to use constructor injection you can add Engine to the arguments of Car provide method. create the marutiCar instance then set the engine to the car.

Comment: another post supporting this : https://github.com/square/dagger/issues/367

Comment: Thanks @Amir Ziarati for your direction. The video by jake wharton devoxx 2014 was also helpful in understanding the concept.